# Songtext from Passenger: "nothing but a rolling stone"

Tags: meaning

What is ment by "A man with nothing in his hands, **nothing but a rolling stone**"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of song lyrics.

Comment: To me it seems on-topic because it's about an English phrase.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a reference to one or more of the following:

- the proverb "[a rolling stone gathers no moss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rolling_stone_gathers_no_moss)",
- the rock band [The Rolling Stones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones),
- the Muddy Waters album [Rollin' Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollin%27_Stone) (after which the rock band were named),
- [Rolling Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_Stone) magazine,
- the Bob Dylan song "[Like a Rolling Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_a_Rolling_Stone)".

Comment: And which of these items might a man hold in his hands?

Comment: @MartinSmith: I read it as "A man who has nothing in his hands; a man who is like a rolling stone" rather than "A man who is holding nothing in his hands except for a rolling stone". YMMV.

Comment: I can see that interpretation is possible.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Although if he is holding something in his hands then it has to be the magazine or one of the records, as the proverb is intangible and the rock band too large and numerous to hold. ;)

Comment: Or could just be a literal stone that he rolls to while away the time but I think you're reading that these are two distinct points makes more sense!

Comment: Papa was a rolling stone,
Where ever he laid his hat was his home
and when he died, all he left us was alone